# How to configure hotspot on a Mikrotik router to provide user and password to other wireless routers?

Tags: wireless-networking, authentication, hotspot, radius, mikrotik-routeros

I have recently purchased a Mikrotik router (RB-951G). There are multiple wireless routers available in my network. They are located in multiple floors. I have connected them to a Cisco small business switch. Further, I have connected the switch to the 2nd port of the Mikrotik router. Mikrotik is then connected to our main firewall. Also it is worth mentioning that the wireless routers are D-Link and TP-Link manufactured.

By configuring a Radius server on the Mikrotik router, is it possible to
provide username and password to every individual that is connecting
to all wireless devices with username and password?

Comment: Please clarify what you’re trying to achieve. You don’t “provide” credentials. Do you want to use WPA2-Enterprise on the access points?

Comment: i dont want to use WPA/WPA2 which is the common authentication type for wireless routers. I want to create usernames and passwords using mikrotik as a radius server and make the wireless security open. so, users can connect to the router but cannot use the internet unless they login to captive portal using their username and password

Comment: Now that’s some information you should definitely [add to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1294865/edit)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's possible to install both captive portal and radius on microtik routers. That being said it really depends on the amount of users you expect to simultaneously connect to your authentication router, and how much horsepower your microtik has under the hood. It may support 10, 20, or 200 depending on model.

You may have to customize these instructions to your needs:

https://www.google.com/amp/www.mikrotik.com.my/hotspot-server-with-captive-portal-and-walled-garden/amp/

Just so you are aware, this is a bad idea if you are running any kind of business communication over the wireless. Anyone would be able to capture your network traffic in real time unadulterated.

If you find your router doesn't have the guts to support the simultaneous users you want connecting. You can go the PFsense route, which also has radius and captive portal. And is pretty easy to get going.

Hope this info helps.